# Search a datagridview column that contains only numbers numbers

Tags: vb.net, search, numbers

I have a search function that works great for datagridview columns that contain text only. The datagridview is generated from an excel spreadsheet using excelreader.
It will find all the entries in that column starting with the letter typed into Textbox3, and list them in the datagrid.

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        TryCast(dgvData.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
           String.Format("Diff like '" & TextBox3.Text & "%'")
    End Sub
```

When I try it on a column that contains only numbers such as "ID_Number" I get the following error code

"System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Double and System.String.'"

Can this be rewritten to allow it to search columns with numbers?

I have tried to change the string.format entry but it seems the .format only accepts string

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Excel or sorting, so I have removed those tags. Please don't apply irrelevant tags because it wastes the time of people who are watching those tags. Even if this data came from Excel in the first place, that doesn't mean that Excel has anything to do with the issue. Also, sorting is a separate operation to filtering.

Comment: As is always the case, you should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation when you have an issue. If you had read the documentation for the `DataView.RowFilter` property then you would have been directed to the topic for the `DataColumn.Expression` property for more information. That page provides all the information on the limited SQL-like syntax supported in that context. As is always the case, `LIKE` operations are only possible on text data, so you would have to convert your numbers to text. That documentation explains how to do that. Starting using the documentation now.

Comment: There's no justification for using `TryCast` in that code. The whole point of `TryCast` is that it won't throw an exception if the cast fails, so you need to test the result for `Nothing`. You're not doing that though, so if your cast failed then you'd get a `NullReferenceException` anyway. If the cast might fail, you need to check the result of `TryCast` for `Nothing`. If it won't fail, don't use `TryCast` in the first place and use `DirectCast` instead.

Comment: Don't do this: `TryCast(dgvData.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter`. Add a `BindingSource` to your form in the designer, then bind your `DataTable` to that and bind it to the grid. You can then just set the `Filter` property of that `BindingSource`.

Comment: The fact that you have controls named `Button3` and `TextBox3` is bad. ALWAYS use descriptive names for everything. That name means nothing to anyone who doesn't already know. That will include you if you put that code down for a while and pick it up again later. The name should tell you what its purpose is.

Comment: Always tidy that up once I know it works. Maybe that’s not the perfect way but it works for me.

Comment: What you do is up to you but I would suggest changing names at the outset. That will make it less likely that you make a mistake and it also means that you won't have to change event handler names like `Button3_Click` and thus cannot forget to do so. It's also better for us if you need to post code to get help, because it's more clear to us what is for what.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you should have read the documentation for the `DataView.RowFilter` property. That would have directed you to the documentation for the `DataColumn.Expression` property for an explanation of the subset of SQL-like syntax supported in those contexts. `LIKE` operations are only supported on text values so you need to convert your numbers to text, not just here but in basically all contexts. The documentation includes a description of a `CONVERT` function, so you're all set. Coupled with my suggestion from the comments to use a `BindingSource` between the `DataTable` and `DataGridView` for data-binding and a bit of string interpolation to clean up the concatenation:

```vb
myBindingSource.Filter = $"CONVERT(Diff, System.String) LIKE '{TextBox3.Text}%'"
```

Comment: Which documentation.? I looked at Learn.microsoft as it was what came up on the majority of searches. If you have a better source then please let me know.

Comment: @PeterW, that is the official documentation. You don't usually need to search though. Just click a type or member in the code window and press F1 to go straight to the documentation for that type or member. For those times you do need to search, bookmark the API documentation home page. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/) is the Australian version that I use.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll go searching the bindingsource

Comment: My program uses exceldatareader. I need to open and read and display in different formats an excel spread sheet whose data varies between forms each spreadsheet. However, the format re columns headings is always the same. Is there any point in binding to a data source that changes frequently?

Comment: @PeterW, that question seems unrelated to the current topic, so asking it in a comment on an answer is not really appropriate.

Comment: I ask a question, you answer to use bindingsource to which I reply is it really suitable and you say it’s unrelated??

Comment: @PeterW, you said *"Is there any point in binding to a data source that changes frequently"*. Nowhere there do you mention a `BindingSource`, so you did not reply as you claim. You're binding to a data source either way, whether you use a `BindingSource` or not. My suggestion for using a `BindingSource` in this case was to make it easier to set a filter.

Comment: So the words “Binding to a data source” and “bindingsource “ is such a huge variation that it is impossible to link the two??

Comment: @PeterW, yes, they are. A `BindingSource` is a specific component. It is the `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource` class. If you're not using that class, you're not using a `BindingSource`. If you are setting the `DataSource` property of your `DataGridView` then you are binding to a data source. It is quite possible to do the latter without doing the former. In fact, you are already binding to a data source in the code you posted in the question. Obviously, the two are different things. Terminology is important in a technical field. If you mean `BindingSource`, say `BindingSource`.

Comment: @PeterW, as for whether you should use a `BindingSource`, I wouldn't have suggested it if I didn't think it was a good idea. You don't have to use one as there's nothing you can do with one that you can't do without. The class didn't even exist until .NET Framework 2.0. What it does do is bring various binding-related functionality together in one place and make it easier to access. In this specific case, direct access to the `Filter` property, rather than the convoluted path you're using to the `DataView.RowFilter` property, is the reason I suggested it. There may also be other benefits.